# NEON intrinsic, compile error "argument must be a constant" when using vshr_n_u32

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon

I got a compile error "argument must be a constant" when using NEON intrinsic `vshr_n_u32`. The function prototype is:

```
__extension__ static __inline uint32x2_t __attribute__ ((__always_inline__))
vshr_n_u32 (uint32x2_t __a, const int __b)
{
  return (uint32x2_t)__builtin_neon_vshr_nv2si ((int32x2_t) __a, __b, 0);
}
```

And here is my function:

```
uint32x2_t shift_func(int index)
{
    int shift_bit[] = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int n_val = shift_bit[index];

    uint32x2_t src_reg = {16, 32};
    return vshr_n_u32(src_reg, n_val);
}
```

The value of `n_val` only can be known at run-time. But according to compile error, it seems that the value of `n_val` should be known at compile-time. Although the type of `__b` is `const int`, I think it should be right to input an int variable.

How to remove the compile error? Or how to use `vshr_n_u32` in this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shift in [vshr_n_u32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/chr1360928374486.html) has to be a compile-time literal constant, as the shift value is encoded as part of the ARM instruction itself. Since you only have a few possible shift values then you might want to use a `switch` statement to handle each case. Or you could just use [vshl_u32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/chr1360928374486.html) with a negative shift (you pass a second `int32x2_t` parameter containing the shift values).